# Shopware 6 (Symfony) - Disable CMS Resolver cache - Possible?

Tags: symfony, shopware6

I have written a CMS element in Shopware 6 and implemented a resolver for it. The resolver works with a session. Unfortunately the resolver is cached after an initial call. Can I disable this for a resolver? The overall cache of the application should of course remain. The problem also exists for subscribers etc. If this should not work, that one deactivates the cache only for a resolver, which solution would you think of for this? Reading information from a session using logic from a PHP script.